# DHL integration into iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, dhl

did someone accomplished the integration for creating shipment labels into objective-c / iOS Code? We're developing an app and want to give users the opportunity to create labels directly in the frontend. I tried it via https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine and through NSMutableRequest without success.

Maybe you can help.
Thank you

Comment: what kind of shipment labels? Do you have a backend already or which API are you trying to use?

Comment: i want to use the german "Privatkundenversand - API" [link](http://www.dhl.de/de/paket/pakete-versenden.html)

i have use the Kinvey Backend [link](https://www.kinvey.com) but, as i said,  if possible i want to integrate it to the iOS frontend just with NSMutableRequest or something like that

i didn't find something in the web

Comment: I cannot see the documentation of the API because I am not registered.